# ipa file increased to double because of assets.car

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcasset

the ipa file was 38 MB and suddenly its 90 MB

I checked the package and found that assets.car increased to double; however I didn't add any new images to assets.

N.B. i'm using pods and xcode 6.3.1

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I had few images (.pdf) added in resources as vector; but actually the images were not vector base. 100 KB image file increased the ipa 20 MB

Just be sure that the (.pdf) images are vector base before setting them as vector